# Selenium Webdriver - How to set proxy to "auto-detect" for Firefox

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

My scripts are running fine on chrome and IE but won't start on firefox due to firefox having "manual" set for its proxy settings. How can I set this to "auto-detect"?

Source code in C# please.

Thanks

Comment: By default what is the proxy setting in your FF browser? That is when you open it manually?

Comment: The default for my normal browser is "auto-detect". However since the Selenium webdriver launches a stripped down version it is set to "manual" in this instant.

Comment: OK, did you already try using a custom profile with proxy set as auto-detect?

Comment: No I did not ... probably because I don't know how! :-( Could you please advise?

Comment: Google is always at your service :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9261133/how-can-i-configure-selenium-webdriver-to-use-custom-firefox-setup-for-tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help AJ.

I used the following code to solve my problem:

```
FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile("C:\\test profile\\");          driver = new FirefoxDriver(binary, profile);
```

I simply copied the contents of my Mozilla profile to `"c:\test profile\"`. This allowed me to run the test via Selenium but also keep other firefox instances open.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to set firefox to auto-detect. go to http://wpad/wpad.dat, it will return the javascript file which set up the proxy. You can find the proxy address inside. 
Then use the following code to do the trick

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
            String PROXY = "xx.xx.xx.xx:8080";
            OpenQA.Selenium.Proxy proxy = new OpenQA.Selenium.Proxy();
            proxy.HttpProxy=PROXY;
            proxy.FtpProxy=PROXY;
            proxy.SslProxy=PROXY;
            profile.SetProxyPreferences(proxy);
            FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add this source to your program:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
String PROXY = "your URL WEB proxy:YourPort";
OpenQA.Selenium.Proxy proxy = new OpenQA.Selenium.Proxy();
proxy.HttpProxy = PROXY;
proxy.FtpProxy = PROXY;
proxy.SslProxy = PROXY;
profile.SetProxyPreferences(proxy);
```