# How to launch google using Selenium Webdriver 2.25.0?

Tags: webdriver

I am encountering a strange thing...If I am launching my Firefox v3.6.2 using my driver scripts then I am not able to open the page.

Server Not found pops up once my Firefox page opens and the url is set.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.co.in");
    }
}
```

Kindly help.

Regards,
Sambit

Comment: Are you connected to internet? Or do you use proxy? The above code should work, so I am guessing some issue with internet connection...

Comment: When I am manually opening Mozilla and pasting the same url its opening the page. But the problem occurs when I am trying to launch my browser using my driver scripts. I dont know whats the issue

Comment: Still it can mean, you are behind proxy and its not set up in webdriver. So ... are you using proxy?

Comment: We have a proxy setup which helps us in hitting the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I am convinced that you are having problem with setting up proxy in Webdriver. Have look at this question: [Selenium Webdriver - How to set proxy to "auto-detect" for Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952217/selenium-webdriver-how-to-set-proxy-to-auto-detect-for-firefox) and try to follow the approach they used. Let me know if it helps

Comment: How to link on the below mentioned ahref? <ahref="/006b0000002Hydl/e?srPos=0&amp;srKp=006&amp;retURL=%2F_ui%2Fcommon%2Fsearch%2Fclient%2Fui%2FUnifiedSearchResults%3F_dc%3D13524441%26searchCount%3D1%26cmdType%3Dcmp%26cmp%3DsingleEntitySearchResult%26fen%3D006%26str%3DTest%2BOpp1%26initialViewMode%3Ddetail%26sen%3D006%" class="actionLink" data-seclke="Opportunity" data-seclkh="d52d6fec96ef9fea1" data-seclki="006b0000002Hydl" data-seclkp="/006b00000l/e" data-seclkr="1" onclick="searchResultClick.click(this)" onmousedown="searchResultClick.click(this)" title="Edit - Record 1 - Test Opp1">Edit</a>