# how to Customize Firefox proxy settings using selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

facing issue in below question, how to set the proxy settings?

```
//sample code to add new proxy settings
firefoxProfile.SetPreference(“network.proxy.http_port”, 8080);
```

Comment: take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9261133/how-can-i-configure-selenium-webdriver-to-use-custom-firefox-setup-for-tests

Answer (score 1):

Check the code shared in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10513746/1069114).

```
//Code copied from the above link
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
String PROXY = "xx.xx.xx.xx:8080";
OpenQA.Selenium.Proxy proxy = new OpenQA.Selenium.Proxy();
proxy.HttpProxy=PROXY;
proxy.FtpProxy=PROXY;
proxy.SslProxy=PROXY;
profile.SetProxyPreferences(proxy);
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Set `PROXY` to your proxy server address.

For Java Users

```
    String PROXY = "proxyserver:9999";
    org.openqa.selenium.Proxy proxy = new org.openqa.selenium.Proxy();
    proxy.setHttpProxy(PROXY);
    proxy.setFtpProxy(PROXY);
    proxy.setSslProxy(PROXY);

    org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities cap = org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    cap.setCapability(org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);

    org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver driver = new org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver(cap);
```

Comment: It didn't worked for me, I was using a proxy server and google tells my real ip not the one I am setting in the proxy option.
Moreover, In C#, `FirefoxProfile` class is obsolete. You can use `FirefoxOptions`.

Answer (score 1):

what worked for me: use `FirefoxOptions` instead of `FirefoxProfile`:

```
var options = new FirefoxOptions();
Proxy proxy = new()
{
   HttpProxy = "xxxxxxx"
};
options.Proxy = proxy;
var driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```